# issue saving uploaded files in django

Tags: django, file, upload, media

I tried the simplest way of saving files in my django media folder
this is my .conf apache wsgi configuration file

```
ServerName testapplication.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/supergestor/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor


Alias /static /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/static/
Alias /media /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/media/

<Directory /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/supergestor>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>


<Directory /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/media/>
Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/static/>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in my settings.py file i set MEDIA_ROOT='/home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/media/'

and MEDIA_URL=''

the media folder is at the root of my project folder, the django project being supergestor

when i tried to upload i've got this error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/seba/git/CNBLUE/supergestor/media'
i have no clue

Comment: Apache generally runs your code as a special user and not you. It thus will not always have access to stuff. Especially in user accounts where files/directories are created with restrictive umask settings. See documentation at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

Answer (score 0):

The `MEDIA_ROOT` should set like this:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/media")
```

And I suggest you check the directory permissions first.